# Issue with :PlugInstall command in Vim (not an editor command)

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug

I'm encountering an issue with the `:PlugInstall` command in Vim and would appreciate some guidance on how to resolve it.

Problem: When attempting to run `:PlugInstall`, Vim responds with `not an editor command`.

Context: Here are some details about my setup:

Plugin Directory: `C:\Users\diego\vimfiles\autoload\plug.vim`

`vimrc` Location: `C:\Users\diego\.vimrc`

Contents of `.vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin(has('nvim') ? stdpath('data') . '/plugged' : '~/.vim/plugged')

" Declare the list of plugins.
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'junegunn/seoul256.vim'
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'

" List ends here. Plugins become visible to Vim after this call.
call plug#end()

" This is necessary for VimTeX to load properly. The "indent" is optional.
" Note that most plugin managers will do this automatically.
filetype plugin indent on

" This enables Vim's and neovim's syntax-related features. Without this, some
" VimTeX features will not work (see ":help vimtex-requirements" for more
" info).
syntax enable

" Viewer options: One may configure the viewer either by specifying a built-in
" viewer method:
let g:vimtex_view_method = 'mupdf'

" Or with a generic interface:
let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer = 'okular'
let g:vimtex_view_general_options = '--unique file:@pdf\#src:@line@tex'

" VimTeX uses latexmk as the default compiler backend. If you use it, which is
" strongly recommended, you probably don't need to configure anything. If you
" want another compiler backend, you can change it as follows. The list of
" supported backends and further explanation is provided in the documentation,
" see ":help vimtex-compiler".
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'


" Most VimTeX mappings rely on localleader and this can be changed with the
" following line. The default is usually fine and is the symbol "\".
let maplocalleader = ","
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. My primary goal is to install VimTeX, and I've been trying to identify the problem without success.

I'm relatively new to using Vim, so any assistance and guidance would be especially helpful.

Comment: You get that error because your plugin manager is not installed correctly or not installed at all. Use its recommended path to [get help](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug?tab=readme-ov-file#getting-help). FWIW, your `vimrc` should be at *either* of the following location: `C:\Users\diego\_vimrc` or `C:\Users\diego\vimfiles\vimrc`. Learn vanilla Vim before getting into plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) is not correctly installed.

You can verify that the installation ran correctly by verifying that you have a `plug.vim` file in in the `~\vimfiles\autoload` folder (`C:\Users\diego\vimfile\autoload` in your case).

Maybe the install failed and you could remove the [plug.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim) file and redo the installation to make sure you have an updated version of the `plug.vim` file.

I would also advice you to use the default plugin folder of [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) instead of overriding it:

```
" Use the default plugin folder:
call plug#begin()
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'junegunn/seoul256.vim'
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
call plug#end()
```

Remark: your original call was:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```

But on Windows it should probably be

```
call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/plugged')
```

Which is actually the default (hence my proposition).

Remark: `~/.vimrc` is an authorized path for the Vim configuration on Windows but the recommendation is to use `~/_vimrc` or `~/vimfiles/vimrc` (see [:help vimrc](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#vimrc))